# How can I edit this question to be more factual

Tags: discussion

[How could impeachment attorneys have answered Lemar Alexander's question factually?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/49952/how-should-impeachment-attorneys-have-answered-lemar-alexanders-question)

I've made an edit to clarify I'm looking for the factual answers, can it be improved on?

House impeachment manager Zoe Lofgren, who was involved in all three modern impeachments, answered.   Conservative sources say she seemed to stumble on this question.   I'm wondering if she could have stuck to the facts?